# Regular Expression for get attribute value

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have used below code to get the regex but not working properly.. Please suggest..

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<category cname='CH1' id='C1'>
<subcat sname='SCName1' sid='SC1'>
```

I want to get sname & sid attributes value of SCName1 & SC1. I've used below code

```
use File::Slurp;
my $filename='nba.xml';
my @lines = read_file( $filename ) ;
foreach (@lines) {
  $_=~/sname\s*=\s*'([^']+)'.*?sid\s*=\s*'([^']+)'/g;
  print "$1,$2\n";
  $comp1="$1";
  $comp2="$2";
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to do this using regex....

```
foreach(@lines)
{
    if($_=~/sname\s*=\s*'([^']+)'.*?sid\s*=\s*'([^']+)'/g)
    {
        $scatval="$1";
        if ($scatval eq $subCateGory)
        {
        $scatid="$2";   
        $scat_flag=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **XML parser** but **not regular expressions** to parse XML!

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'EOT');
<root>
<category cname='CH1' id='C1'/>
<subcat sname='SCName1' sid='SC1'/>
</root>
EOT

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($doc);

my $sname = $xpc->findvalue('//subcat/@sname');
my $sid = $xpc->findvalue('//subcat/@sid');
```